# Using Ghostscript to compress pdf file

Tags: pdf, compression, ghostscript

I'm trying to compress a pdf file using ghostscipt. I've been using both ebook and screen default parameters, but I would like to find a way to obtain a result in between the two. Is there any way to achieve this manually and if yes what would be the parameters ?
Thanks :)

Comment: The documentation is here: https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html#common-controls-and-features The PDFSETTINGS are defined in that, you can choose which you want to alter individually. Note that what you are doing isn't really compressing the file. You are either discarding non-marking data (eg Illustrator saves a complete cpoy of it's file in the PDF and can be discarded) or reducing quality (such as downscaling images).  We also have a blog post which covers this topic https://www.ghostscript.com/blog/optimizing-pdfs.html

Comment: Hi ! Thanks, I couldn't find this page in the documentation ;) !